# YUN - openssh-sftp-server gone from Linino opkg repository

Tags: arduino

I installed newest version of linino on my arduino Yun (Linino Barrier Breaker devel). The only thing missing is openssh-sftp-server that I was using heavily, opkg list shows no trace of it. Does anyone know of a good alternative to launch sftp server on Yun or how to install it? I tried to make downloaded version of openssh-sftp-server but linion lacks a C compiler(at least thats wat the error log says). I could really use a precompiled version. Does anyone know of an alternative repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the standard repository list to latest!

```
vi /etc/opkg.conf
```

and replace the first line with this one

```
http://http://download.linino.org/dogstick/all-in-one/latest/packages/
```

update the packages with

```
opkg update
```

and now you can install openssh-sftp-server

```
opkg install openssh-sftp-server
```